# Populating ExpandableListView Header and Child with arrays in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, expandablelistview

I have two string arrays in my resources. First is

arr_song_title contains:

- Love on Top
- Pricetag
- Titanium
- It will rain

and second array strings are the artist:

- Beyonce
- Jessie J.
- David Guetta
- Bruno Mars

++Header++

--Child

++Header++

--Child

++Header++

--Child

What I want is to place the title as headers in expandable listview and the artist as item.

What I know is to create the header manually and populate it with arrays. How to do this?

Here is my code:

```
listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

String[] a = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arr_title);
String[] b = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arr_artist);

for ( String str : a ) {
    listDataHeader.add(str);
}
int counter = 0;
List<String> artist = new ArrayList<String>();
for ( String str : b ) {
    artist.add(str);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(counter), artist);
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with `place the title as headers in expandable listview and the artist as item.`? where is your code for Create Expandable list?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan With that code, each headers contains all the array contents as its child.

For example:

Love on Top (Header) contains:
Beyonce (child of Love on Top)
Jessie J. (child of Love on Top)
David Guetta (child of Love on Top)
Bruno Mars (child of Love on Top)

Comment: did you want each title have an artist? like Beyonce is Love on Top, Jessie J is  Pricetag and so on? each one artist has one title?

Comment: in your example one problem exist ( in my look ) that is first header has one child , second header has two child, third header has three child and so on , and it's happened because you must clear  `artist` list after setting one data to your `HashMap`

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan that's what I expected too. But the result is that the first header contains all the artist, and so to the second header. If I cleared the artist inside the loop, no content shown.only header remained

Comment: please put your artist in one List<List<String>> and check output

Comment: As you can see, artist variable is of type List<String>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46330/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-ajdeguzman)